# Every n × n-matrix A with real entries has at least one real eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a true/false question:

```
Every n × n-matrix A with real entries has at least one real eigenvalue.
```

I am thinking that this is true but I would like to hear other opinions.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if the next T/F question asks the same for odd $n$.

Comment: On the practice test? I am asking the ones that I am unsure of.

Comment: Yes. ${{{{}}}}$

Comment: Why do you think this is being marked?

Comment: I don't think that. I'm just wondering what I mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were asking why I was asking too many T/F questions, assuming that I was only asking the odd ones because in schools they usually ask only either even or odd questions

Comment: But the next T/F question does not ask that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope. Try a rotation in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: I tried the identity rotation and I found the answer is yes:-)+1

Answer (score 9):

Since the eigenvalues of a matrix $A\in\mathcal M_n(\Bbb R)$ are roots of its characteristic  polynomial then the question is equivalent to say:
 "every polynomial with real coefficients has a real root" which is wrong.

**Remark:** The answer is yes if we more assume  that $n$ is odd (why?).

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that every polynomial is the characteristic polynomial of some linear transformation?

Comment: Do you know the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)?

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, I forgot.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a counterexample:

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       -4 & 1         \\[0.3em]
     \end{bmatrix}

Being clever, we can construct any number of $2 \times 2$ matrices such that its characteristic polynomial has negative discriminant, and thus has no real roots (eigenvalues).

Answer (score 2):

Eigenvalues of a $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2 - \text{tr}(M)\lambda + \det(M)$. All you need to do is find a $2\times 2$ matrix where $\text{tr}(M)^2-4\det(M)<0$ to find a counterexample.